# Comparing args value with string in java

Tags: java

I am trying out this code

```
catch (Exception e) {
 
String s="-help";
String s1="[-help]";
  if(s.equals(args) || s1.equals(args))
  {
    System.out.println("hello");
  }
  else 
  {
  log.info(e.getMessage());
  
  HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
  formatter.printHelp("AutoLockComponent ", options, true);
 
  }
  
  
}
```

But every single time while i am trying to debug the code it always going to else block instead of going into if condition,i mean the output that is am excepting is "hello" but i am getting log.info message printed, can anyone help me out in this, your help will be really appreciated, Also i am attaching the debugger info image for args value.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`args` is an array. Not a string. In the specific case you want `args[0]`.

```
if(s.equals(args[0]) || s1.equals(args[0]))
```